# How to get the number of bits from a scalar of type (SYNTAX BITS) in mib2c.conf?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

I couldn't find anything in "man mib2c.conf". Is there something like $var.length/$var.size by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it doesn't have a size/length.  But it does have the enums available from which you could determine the size.  Here's a hack that will get you the maximum enum value, which would mean that the size will be that many bits:

```
@perleval $vars{'max'} = 0@
@foreach $label, $value enums@
  @perleval $vars{'max'} = ($vars{'max'} < $vars{'value'} ? $vars{'value'} : $vars{'max'}); return 0;@
@end@
max: $max
```

When this is put in a loop over the mteTriggreTable columns for example, you get:

```
...
mteTriggerEnabled:
  max: 2
mteTriggerEntryStatus:
  max: 6
```

Comment: `perleval $vars{'size'} = 0@`
`@foreach $label, $value enums@
  @perleval $vars{'size'} = $vars{'size'} + 1; return 0;@
@end@
size: $size`

Comment: That's only helpful if the bit numbers are contiguous.  My way using a max comparison was safer if there are missing bits in the middle (which there shouldn't be, but.....)